# Move firefox tab group into new window

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I've got grouped my firefox tabs in three tab groups now using the native tab group handling, but always forget that the groups are there - the tab groups icon on the top right doesn't give an indication that there is more than the current set of tabs.

To make the groups more visible, I'd like to move one (or all) tab groups into their own window.

I did not find an in-built way to do this, nor did I find an extension for this.

What can I do?

---

(I do not want to bookmark all tabs, open a new window and then open all the bookmarks. I simply want to move a tab group into its own window.)

This question was [already discussed in 2011](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2139281) with no real solution back then. But maybe times have changed.

Comment: Sorry, not aware of any solution other than dragging them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I'd like to move one (or all) tab groups into their own window.

The Firefox Add-on [Multiple Tab Handler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multiple-tab-handler/) appears to meet your requirements.

You can:

1. Select a tab group (tabs in this group will be displayed)
2. Select the tabs in the group (can be done with the mouse)
3. Right click and select "Move to New Window"

Note:

This extension may conflict with other tab related extensions.

For example [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) uses some of the same short cut keys to select multiple tabs.

---

#### What is the Multiple Tab Handler extension?

> **About this Add-on**
>
> This provides features to handle multiple tabs at once, for example,
> close them, reload them, and so on. When you press the mouse button
> and dragging over tabs, they will be selected. (Note: The tab will be
> just moved, if you move the mouse quickly.
>
> To start selection, you have to keep the button pressed and wait for a
> while.)
>
> After you release the button, the popup to choose command will be
> shown. Of course, you can toggle selection by Ctrl-click on each tab
> and call features from the context menu. Yes, the behavior looks like
> Excel.
>
> Buit-in features for selected tabs:
>
> - Close selected tabs
> - Close not-selected tabs
> - Reload selected tabs
> - Duplicate selected tabs
> - Pin/unpin selected tabs (Minefield/Firefox 4)
> - Move selected tabs to a group (Minefield/Firefox 4)
> - **Move selected tabs to a new window**
> - Bookmark selected tabs
> - Copy URIs/titles+URIs/HTML links for selected tabs to the clipboard
> - Save (download) selected tabs to the local disk
> - Print selected tabs (require Print All Tabs: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/5142)

Source [Multiple Tab Handler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multiple-tab-handler/)

Answer (score 0):

I've found [Tab Groups](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-groups-panorama/) to be a suitable alternative, similar to Session Buddy in Chrome. There are a few extensions which work with it like [Tab Groups Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-groups-helper/) which make it more versatile.